# typedefs in Java

Tags: android, c, typedef

Is there an equivalent to typedefs in Java?  I would like to define them similar to how you would in a c header:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned char Integer8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef int UINT32;
```

Comment: in my .h library defined as typedef unsigned char Integer8 ,what can i use in my java class,similar to this in .java wrapper class for .h file